# How to find out Exact Control in WPF DataGridColoumnHeader Style

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, datagridcolumnheader

I'm having a `DataGridColumnHeader` Sytle, in that I'm having a `Button` for Filtering. I need to find out which button is currently working (i.e., which button gets fired), based on that I need to write trigger action for that appropriate `Button`.

My XAML Style is

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DummyFilterDataGridColumnHeader">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
              <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.FilterPopUpCommand, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                  <Button.CommandParameter>
                      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverterKey}">
                          <Binding RelativeSource="{ RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType={x:Type cust:DataGrid}}" />
                          <Binding Path="Column" 
                                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" />
                      </MultiBinding>
                  </Button.CommandParameter>
              </Button>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

> Note: I need to set Button Visibility based on Button Click. After
>   Clicking the Popup gets display after the Popup gets Closed then I
>   want to set the Visibility to Collapsed.

Comment: A Button for sorting ? The DataGrid header already supports sorting when klicking on it .. ?!

Comment: @FeDe Sorry Its Filtering...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Add the Button itself to the `<Button.CommandParameters/>`

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

This will get you the Button itself to your Method you are calling if clicked.

Inside your ClickEventHandler, where you open the PopUp you can set the Visibility for the Button you got from the parameters.

Hope this helps

Comment: I need to set Button Visibility based on Button Click. After Clicking the Popup gets display after the Popup gets Closed then I want to set the Visibility to Collapsed.

Comment: Sounds more like a ToggleButton :D Try using a ToggleButton and create a Style that triggers on the Toggle to set Visibility

Comment: Your Code is not fit for my actual requirement. I tested it... Kindly try to answer my question - "How to find out Exact Control in WPF DataGridColoumnHeader Style" to write datatrigger.

Comment: First let me get it right: Pls correct me if wrong... You want to get the exact button which is in the GridHeader and set its visibility when clicked ?

Comment: Yes. I'm having one bool Property IsPopUpOpen, it denotes the Popup is opened or not. Based on the Property I need to set the Visibility. If True then Visibility is set to Visible otherwise Collapsed.